# Installing a NuGet package from command-line from a private feed

Tags: nuget

Is it possible to fetch a NuGet package from a private feed (i.e., requiring login/password) within a script?

I have a NuGet package with a single JSON file. It's hosted on a private TeamCity feed. I want to use that JSON in a script, so here's what I'm trying to do:

```
nuget sources add -Name tc -Source https://xxxxxxxxx/ -Username username -Password password
nuget install xxxxxxxx -source tc
nuget sources remove -Name tc
```

Which results into `Unable to find version '1.0.7' of package 'xxxxxxx'.` Which is strange, for it's obviously able to reach the feed since it see the version of the package, but can't download the package.

I also tried to install the package into a dummy .sln and run `nuget restore xxxxx.sln`. NuGet is then asks me to provide credentials, two times:

```
Please provide credentials for: https://xxxxxxxx/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/xxxxx.svc/
Please provide credentials for: https://xxxxxxxx/httpAuth/repository/download/xxxxx/1148145:id/xxxxxxxx.1.0.7.nupkg
```

Creating a `NuGet.config` with a feed & credentials declaration also results into the same `Unable to find` error.

It works OK when I'm installing/restoring the package from VS.

These two questions seems related:

- [NuGet Package Restore Unable to prompt for credentials with custom feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467174/nuget-package-restore-unable-to-prompt-for-credentials-with-custom-feed)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682237/nuget-command-line-authentication-not-working

Comment: Which version of NuGet.exe are you using? I had similar problems with restore on Team City when using the latest NuGet.exe 2.8.2 (2.8.50506.491) but using 2.8.1 (2.8.50320.36) seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a problem with the TC feed. I didn't think that was the case because I can use the feed from VS Package Manager, the problem is only with command-line NuGet.

I turned on `-Verbosity detailed` ([thanks danliu](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4210)) and here's what I saw:

```
GET https://xxxxxx/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/Packages(Id='xxxxxx',Version='1.0.7')
GET https://xxxxxx/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/Packages(Id='xxxxxx',Version='1.0.7.0')
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '1.0.7' of package 'xxxxxx'.
```

The request `GET https://xxxxxx/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/Packages(Id='xxxxxx',Version='1.0.7')` returns 404, I think it's related to server configuration problem which is mentioned in TeamCity NuGet feed settings:

```
NuGet Feed must contain server URL inside. Current TeamCity server configuration does not let TeamCity server to get original request URL from HTTP request. It looks like TeamCity server is wrongly configured with reverse proxy. Make sure reverse proxy and TeamCity server is configured to let TeamCity server know request real request URL.
```

I tried to host the package on MyGet and install it from there. It worked out.